# Что означает tr align="center"?

Tags: html, css

Что означает `tr align="center"`?

Answer (score 4):

Но лучше написать с использованием CSS:

```css
.center td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="center">
    <td>Center</td>
    <td>Zentrum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Usual cells</td>
    <td>without centering</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Атрибут `align` ещё в HTML 4 был объявлен *нежелательным* (deprecated).